# Is it possible to pin source packages? If so, how?

Tags: apt, source-packages, pinning

Given this `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb     http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb     http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco  main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco  main restricted universe multiverse
```

and this `/etc/apt/preferences` file:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=cosmic
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release a=disco
Pin-Priority: -10
```

Running `apt install some-package` will install the version from `cosmic`, as I'd expect.

However, running `apt source some-package` will download the (newer) version from `disco`.

How can I make `apt source` obey pin-priorities?

Comment: Which Ubuntu you are having. If you dont know run `lsb_release -a` an post the output.

Comment: @Vijay it is pretty obvious, since he pinned cosmic (18.10) of which I assume  is his current main and disco (19.04)

Comment: @smammy can you please try to use `apt source -t cosmic <package name>` and tell me if this works for you?

Comment: @Videonauth yes, that works, but I was hoping not to have to remember to use the `-t` switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is not possible, per a friend of a friend on the APT team. `apt source` doesn't pay attention to pinning.

Comment: Good to know, as I was fiddling around in a VM to find a way :)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking source packages are a different namespace than binary packages. A very recent version of apt (post-Buster, even, so it's only in testing+ right now) started to support pinning *by* source package instead of binary package, using a `src:` prefix.

I would've set up the following pinning entry if Buster supported it already for preferring Ceph 14 packages (from backports) over the stale v12 ones from stable, for example:

```
Package: src:ceph
Pin: version 14.*
Pin-Priority: 1002
```

Rather a lot better than having to enumerate the dozens of binary packages generated from that one source.

I've checked with a more recent apt and sadly even with this new feature, `apt source` still ignores pinning. :-(