# Updating Ubuntu Base updates Nvidia Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, cuda

I'm working on a Ubuntu 20.04 System with Cuda installed and a specific version of the Nvidia Drivers (Driver: 450.119.03). I wanted to run the security updates, including the one for Ubuntu Base. However, this update also installs Nvidia 460 Drivers, even though they are not mentioned in the packages. I've tried multiple times and made extra sure that nothing with Nvidia or Cuda is mentioned in the Details of the Ubuntu Base update - but still when I install that security update my Nvidia updates and Cuda is broken due to a driver mismatch.

Is there a way to install updates without installing them for the Nvidia Drivers automatically via the Base update?

Comment: So long as you’re [not using `apt source`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123639/1222991), you should be able to [mark apt packages as being on hold](https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/1222991) 

Comment: Thank you, trying to do so with Synaptic Package Manager now.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

@matigo posted a solution. I locked all relevant installed packages using Synaptic. All packages with "nvidia", "cuda" or "CuDNN" in their name were locked and then could update without a problem.